# Predecessor impacting project completion time

Tags: ms-project

I am using MS project for the first time. I am having difficulty understanding how to configure predecessor correctly. My current setup is causing my project to take longer than my goal time of 8 months (current setup has my completion in 1 year). I believe my predecessor setup is causing this issue, but I’m unsure how to adjust the predecessor to lower my completion time. Without a predecessor in place, I am receiving an error which states that I am over allocating my resources. Can someone please advise?

I’ve included a snapshot of my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3BiD.jpg)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

I’ve tried setting up and removing certain predecessors.

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or SuperUser site.

Comment: Aside from Rachel's comment, I took a look at the screen shot you posted. Since it doesn't show the ID field, it is difficult to determine exactly which tasks are predecessors. However, assuming the top summary line is NOT the Project summary task, in some cases summary lines show as predecessors for subtasks. This is bad practice. Summary lines are NOT tasks and should have neither dependencies (predecessors/successors) nor resource assigned. Please re-post to the Project Management site Rachel referenced and someone will help you there.